# connect a dataset to Australia map with r

Tags: r, dictionary, dataset, geospatial

I have a question about how to connect a dataset to Australian map with r. 
Now I have a dataset like: 
Each row represents for a person who is from a state of Australia

```
Name State 

A    SA

B    VIC

C    NSW

D    QLD

E    QLD

F    SA
```

I want to draw a choropleth map to show how many people from each state. 
Now I find a Australian map from package "oz"

https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/oz/oz.pdf

I can get each state by these codes below:

```
library(oz)

oz(sections=6) # Tasmania

oz(sections=c(7,8,10,12,14,16)) # South Australia
```

I am thinking I could connect my dataset to the map by using state name, but oz gets each state by sections, not state name. I don't know how to connect my dataset to the map?  Anyone could help?

Comment: Perhaps this guide would be helpful: https://blog.exploratory.io/making-maps-for-australia-states-and-local-government-areas-in-r-d78edb506f37

Comment: You can merge the sections to create the states/territories you require or try gadm? https://gadm.org/download_country_v3.html